# How can I make git diff make clearer patches

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

If I have this file

```
def main():
    foo
    bar
    baz
    quux
    corge
```

and I change it to

```
def other():
    foo
    bar
    baz

def main():
    other()
    quux
    corge
```

I really want to see the diff

```
+def other():
+    foo
+    bar
+    baz
+
 def main():
+    other()
-    foo
-    bar
-    baz
     quux
     corge
```

but `git diff` gives me

```
-def main():
+def other():
     foo
     bar
     baz
+
+def main():
+    other()
     quux
     corge
```

(with *every* diff algorithm it offers, patience, minimal, histogram and myers).  Is there some way to persuade it to generate semantically clearer diffs?

Comment: afaik not in command line but you can toggle diff split / diff unified in browser: https://github.com/blog/1884-introducing-split-diffs also this might be helpful information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350678/github-style-split-diffs-on-a-command-line

Comment: Try adding `--diff-algorithm=patience`. I do not know if it will work in this case, but this is the _sort of_ thing it's meant to improve.

Comment: @Mort Sadly it doesn't in this case, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a difference engine that understands the semantics of the language involved.  These are rare.  Although it's been closed as off topic, see [syntax aware diff tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3450907/1256452)  Typical diffs split at line or word boundaries, and then find a *minimum edit distance*, which is *the shortest set of operations that will change the A version into the B version*.  It does not have to make any sense semantically, it just has to be short.  Git's built-in algorithms search for "short" (not always short*est*, as the default `myers` algorithm uses heuristics to produce a result faster) but not "semantically sensible".  The built-in alternative algorithms are:

- `minimal`: same as `myers` but avoids the shortcuts to produce truly minimal edit distances.
- `patience`: matches only on *unique* lines when building boxes for myers-style diff.  For programming languages with repeated brace or `then`/`else`/`endif` lines that produce meaningless matches, this can give better results.
- `histogram`: instead of discarding repeated lines in each box, adds *weighting* to the matches based on the frequency of the occurrence of the lines.  The more-frequent lines get lower weighting.  In theory, this should produce the best results (given the basic issues with non-"syntax-aware" diff).

Obviously, you've tried these and none are as good as a syntax-aware diff.

Assuming you have obtained or written a better diff, you can then plug it into Git as an *external diff* utility.  See [How do I view 'git diff' output with a visual diff program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/255202/1256452) and [Why doesn't `git diff` invoke external diff tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24966271/1256452)